# How to edit multiple lines by keyboard only?

Tags: ms-word, notepad++, ssms

In several editors there is a feature to edit multiple lines pressing Alt + using the Mouse. I would like to produce this 'multiline-cursor' by means of the keyboard only without using a mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++ column mode editing can be invoked by holding the Alt and Shift keys down, then using the arrow keys to extend the selected area. See the [Notepad++ wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Column_Editing). See also Notespad++ menu => **Edit** => **Column mode** which shows a popup with a brief usage tip.

Comment: Thanks! This shortcut also works with the editor in SSMS. (MS-Word does not work this way.)